# RPi 4 - cant get cron job to work (Python, virtual env)

Tags: cron, raspberry-pi

Trying to run a cron job on a RPi 4. It should execute a Python script with a virtual env. I have tried all the common solutions that I found, but it doesn't work. I have very little knowledge of Linux. My Pi should have a default setup (I did not change much).

What I tried:

#1
`07 11 * * * cd /home/pi/Scripts/Retail-Folders && /home/pi/Scripts/Retail-Folders/folders_venv/bin/python /home/pi/Scripts/Retail-Folders/main.py`

#2

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
07 11 * * * cd /home/pi/Scripts/Retail-Folders && /home/pi/Scripts/Retail-Folders/folders_venv/bin/python /home/pi/Scripts/Retail-Folders/main.py
```

#3
`07 11 * * * cd /home/pi/Scripts/Retail-Folders && . /home/pi/Scripts/Retail-Folders/folders_venv/bin/activate /home/pi/Scripts/Retail-Folders/main.py`

I don't believe this should be that hard. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: by the way, the python file is made executable.

Comment: You did not include what your error is.

Comment: I don't see an error anywhere.
In /var/log/syslog I see that the command was sent. Then it said 'No MTA installed discarding output'. I tried creating an output log by adding  >> /home/pi/Scripts/logs/cronlog.log 2>&1 to the end of the cron job, but no log file is created.

Comment: Have you considered using a systemd service and timer? Although it's a little bit more complicated to setup it's easier to debug... If that's an viable option for you I can formulate an answer.

Comment: I'm happy with any solution that works. Cron job seemed to fit my knowledge level, but can't get it to work. If you would be willing to help me with systemd service and timer that would be great, but it would need to be rather plug n play as I normally don't work with Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so in the end I figured out what went wrong. It concerns a script that runs Selenium and my RPi is not attached to a monitor. Apparently that does not work with cron until you specify 'DISPLAY=:0'. This was the solution for me.

Even though I greatly appreciate the answer by criztovyl, I feel like I should mark this as the solution as it explains my original issue. Please correct me if this is not according to convention.

Final crontab to make it work:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
DISPLAY=:0
40 15 * * * cd /path/to/folder && /path/to/venv/bin/python main.py >> /path/to/logfile.txt 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a systemd Service & Timer instead, while they are slightly more complicated to set up, they are easier to debug:

1. create a wrapper script
2. create a service
3. create a timer triggering that service
4. enable the timer

the wrapper script, place to `/home/pi/Scripts/Retail-Folders/run.sh`

Do not skip the `#!` (shebang) line, otherwise systemd cannot run the script.

Don't forget to make the file executable... `chmod +x ...`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cd $(dirname $0)

# your code follows

source folders_venv/bin/activate

./main.py
```

In `/etc/systemd/system` you need root privileges for editing files, i.e. use `sudo <your-editor>`.

The service unit, `/etc/systemd/system/Retail-Folders.service`.

I have included `User` so it runs as the `pi` user, normally it would run as root.

```
[Unit]
Description=Retail Folders Description (optional)

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/pi/Scripts/Retail-Folders/run.sh
User=pi
```

the timer, `/etc/systemd/system/Retail-Folders.timer`.

From the cron pattern you provided it seems you want to run at 11:07 each day, I have included that. For systemd's timer pattern check [`man systemd.time`'s "Calendar Events"](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.time.html#Calendar%20Events), you might find `systemd-analyze calendar --iterations=5 '11:07:00'` useful for verifying the pattern.

The `[Install] WantedBy` tells systemd to enable the timer "for" multi-user target.

```
[Unit]
Description=Timer for Retail Folders

[Timer]
OnCalendar=11:07
Unit=Retail-Folders

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Reload systemd to read the new units:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

test the service, check it's status and log.

```
sudo systemctl start Retail-Folders

sudo systemctl status Retail-Folders
sudo journalctl --unit Retail-Folders
```

If that works fine, you can go on and enable the timer so it will start after also after a reboot.
`--now` starts up the timer directly, without it you would have to issue an `start Retail-Folders.timer` manually.

```
sudo systemctl enable --now Retail-Folders.timer
```

Hope that helps!